# Compile arrow functions into regular functions with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions

Quite a simple question, but I haven't found an answer yet anywhere: Is there some switch to make TypeScript compile arrow functions into plain JavaScript functions?

I use them a lot in my code, and I don't want to rewrite everything. But I lately realized, that IE doesn't support them.

I already tried to switch the script version to ES5, but then my code won't compile anymore, because I'm using "filter" as well, which doesn't seem to be a part of it. However, I don't know, if that would do the job in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to just convert your arrow functions to regular functions and keep the rest of the code compiling, you can set the `target` config to `es5` and `lib` property to `es6`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    // ....
}
```

This will allow your code that uses ES6 features to compile while targeting ES5. But you have to make sure those features (like `filter`) are available at runtime. If they are not available it will throw runtime exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I changed my setting accordingly. However, now it throws 221 errors, including such weird things as "Build: Name "document" could not be found." (Translated from German). It also can't find stuff such as XMLHttpRequest, navigator, and even HTMLElement. What's going wrong there?

Comment: Add `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]` if you are building for the browser.

Comment: Thank you. I already found that answer in the mean time by myself. Everything works fine now, even in IE. I just had to add another polyfill. You really saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions are a part of ES6, but you should be able to transpile your code to ES5 with Babel. There is a [babel-preset-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-typescript) which you should be able to use for this.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I already solved it with @Saravana's solution.