# Angular 5 this undefined inside array.filter

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter, angular5

Here is the code which I was trying

```
search(){
   this.toDisplay = this.products.filter(function(x){
      return this.checkCondition(x.price, condition);
   }
}
```

It is complicated condition like greater than, range, max on the basis of condition number, this function decides condition meet or not and return true or false;

```
checkCondition(item, condition){
  switch(conditoin){
    case 1:  ... brea;
    case 2:  ... brea;
    case 3:  ... brea;

  }
  return status;
}
```

Problem is that when i use `this.checkCondition` inside the filter, always throw `checkCondition` property of undefined, means `this` is undefined.

I checked `this` is always undefined, so how to call a function  inside the filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so that `this` is automatically bound correctly.  Since you tagged TypeScript, you can transpile the arrow functions if you plan on supporting browsers that only support ES5 and down:

```
search(){
   this.toDisplay = this.products.filter(x => this.checkCondition(x.price, condition));
}
```

If you don't want to use arrow functions, you can capture the `this`:

```
search(){
   var selfRef = this;
   this.toDisplay = this.products.filter(function(x) {
      return selfRef.checkCondition(x.price, condition);
   });
}
```

One other method is to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
search(){
   this.toDisplay = this.products.filter(function(x) {
      return selfRef.checkCondition(x.price, condition);
   }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Arrow function still not supported by all the browsers specially on different devices, thanks for you quick reply

Comment: @AliAdravi Since you're using TypeScript though, you shouldn't actually have to worry; the arrow function will transpile to whatever is supported automatically [if you tell it to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46484985/691711).

Comment: Man you made my day, I always scared to use the arrow function even in Type Script, A HUGE thanks for this point

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to assign 'this' to a local variable outside the filter call (People commonly use 'that' or 'self' as an identifier for this purpose).

Example:

```
search(){
   var that = this;
   this.toDisplay = this.products.filter(function(x){
      return that.checkCondition(x.price, condition);
   }
}
```

Comment: I actually added this as an edit to my answer at the same time you posted.  If you can't use arrow functions, this is definitely a good solution.  You should add an example though.